# 425 foot run for 50 amp camper service

Tags: electrical, wiring

I need to run 50 amp service to a camper site 425 feet from my meter box.  I'll likely run it into a small breaker box so I can have a couple outlets to use for lighting and boat battery charging from that same location as well.  What size breaker at the home breaker box will I need, and what size line will I need to run?  I'd prefer to just direct bury if possible but will run conduit if necessary.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well... you'll need a 50a breaker for the 50a RV plug. How much will the boat battery charger draw? Direct burial cable is "best" now, but a pain should someone accidentally dig into it or a critter decide it makes a good lunch.

Answer (score 2):

Wire adds resistance to a circuit, long lengths add enough that voltage to the load is reduced enough to effect the load. Larger wire has less resistance and is used to reduce voltage drop.

The US and Canada are different on this, the NEC that is used in the US only *recommends* a maximum voltage drop of 5%, where as Canada has a specific requirement. The US 5% is a good number to work with, but exceeding that fractionally is not a big issue. I am not familiar with the Canadian rules.

There are several [Voltage Drop Calculators](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-vdrop) on the internet. Some people will instruct you to enter 80% of breaker rating since many sections (constant loads, motors, heat) of the Code limit to that. Don't do that, you need to know your voltage drop when at peak current, and is when motors would suffer most.

For the data provided 2-2-2-4 Aluminum Mobile Home Feeder is a good choice, and is a high volume product that is often cheaper than the next size smaller wire.

50A will result  in about 5.2% loss, I would be perfectly comfortable with that. The maximum breaker you would be allowed to feed that with would be 90A, but 60 or 70 is all you really need. You could mount a 100A rated panel at camper location. 100A or larger is higher than you need for your loads, you could mount a 60A or smaller main breaker panel, but  you are pushing the limits of your needs and will only save a few dollars.

For an amateur pulling wire into 400' of conduit might create more problems than it will solve, just make sure your wire is direct burial rated. There are burial cover depth requirements in [NEC Table 300.5](https://thompsonlearningco.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Table-300.5.jpg) that qualify depth based on location and conduit type, cover means depth of material over the conduit, not the depth of trench.

The NEC is not national law, it becomes law when adopted by State local jurisdictions and is subject to amendments by those jurisdictions.

Comment: 3% hard limit on voltage drop in Canada, per past discussion.

Answer (score 1):

NoSparksPlease's answer covers the wire size issue quite well.

For ease of installation, rather than putting together your own combination of subpanel + breakers, etc. you may want to get an **RV pedestal** like [this GE from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-RV-Pad-Mount-Pedestal-with-50-Amp-and-30-Amp-RV-Receptacles-and-20-Amp-GFCI-Receptacle-GE1LU532PS/300325107):

[image: GE pedestal]

These are available as pedestals designed to be in the ground, mounted to a pad or (much smaller) mounted to a pole. You don't need a separate disconnect because the panel is small (typically 1 double breaker and 2 single breakers, though they can include more spaces for additional circuits) so Rule of 6 applies.

These typically include:

- 50A 240V double-breaker with receptacle - that's what you need for your camper.
- 30A 120V single-breaker with receptacle - for many smaller RVs
- 20A 120V single-breaker with GFCI/receptacle - for plugging in other stuff

Supply is a minimum of 50A. Generally speaking you won't use the 50A and 30A at the same time. But feeding it with 60A or 70A will allow you to run the 20A circuit with a reasonable amount of power even while your 50A circuit is using a lot of power.

Things are changing though. Depending on local code adoption, you may need GFCI for the 30A and/or 50A circuits. That complicates things a bit, as you will need to do that at the breakers because there are not any generally available receptacles with GFCI built-in larger than 20A.